# Is not reusing created SOAP client object

Tags: php, class, soap

Can anyone tell me why the SOAP client is not being re-used? It keeps getting initialized where it should have been reused from the last call.

When I print out the SOAP client object after it was initialized it is there but it is forgotten at the next call.

So the php script keeps initializing the connection.

My code:

```
class EcoAPI {

private $client;

public function getClient() {

    if (empty($this->client)) {
        echo "<br>initializing...";
        $this->initClient();
    }

    return $this->client;
}

private function initClient() {

    $settingsOld = Settings::GetOld();
    $this->client = new SoapClient("https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebservice.asmx?WSDL", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1));
    $this->client->ConnectWithToken(array('token' => $settingsOld->economic_token_secret, 'appToken' => $settingsOld->economic_token_app));        

}
}
```

I connect by:

```
$ecoApi = new EcoAPI();     
$result = $ecoApi->getClient()->Account_GetVatAccount(array('accountHandle' => (object) array('Number' => (string) $VatAccount)));
```

Comment: You could try making the `client` property static? It sounds like you're instantiating a new SOAP client every time you invoke a new EcoAPI class. Ex: `$result = EcoAPI::client->Account_GetVatAccount(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you're creating a new EcoAPI object, it won't have any SOAP client information. Using `$ecoApi->getClient()->...` throughout your code SHOULD work as long as you're using injecting the same `$ecoApi` object.

If you want to ensure that every EcoAPI object has the same connection object, no matter what, you could try making the client a static property with static methods to manipulate the SOAP object.

```
class EcoAPI {

    static private $client;

    static public function getClient() {
        if (empty(self::$client)) {
            echo "<br>initializing...";
            self::initClient();
        }
        return self::$client;
    }

    static private function initClient() {
        $settingsOld = Settings::GetOld();
        self::$client = new SoapClient("https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebservice.asmx?WSDL", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1));
        self::$client->ConnectWithToken(array('token' => $settingsOld->economic_token_secret, 'appToken' => $settingsOld->economic_token_app));        
    }
}
```

And connect by:

```
$result = EcoAPI::getClient()->Account_GetVatAccount(array('accountHandle' => (object) array('Number' => (string) $VatAccount)));
```

Granted, I would advise against using static objects and methods and it can lead to tight coupling. The best method, in my opinion, is injecting your instantiated objects on an as-needed basis.